# Returning input values in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

Given this code:

```
Example.Data<- data.frame(matrix(vector(), 0, 3, dimnames=list(c(), c("Value", "Variable", "Fill"))), stringsAsFactors=F)

Example.Data[1, ] <- c(45, 'Horizontal Pattern','Horizontal Pattern' )
Example.Data[2, ] <- c(65, 'Vertical Pattern','Vertical Pattern' )
Example.Data[3, ] <- c(89, 'Mesh Pattern','Mesh Pattern' )
Example.Data[4,] <- c(20, 'Diagonal Pattern','Diagonal Pattern' )

HighlightDataVert<-Example.Data[2, ]
HighlightHorizontal<-Example.Data[1, ]
HighlightMesh<-Example.Data[3, ]
HighlightHorizontal$Value<-as.numeric(HighlightHorizontal$Value)
Example.Data$Value<-as.numeric(Example.Data$Value)


Example.Data$Variable = Relevel(Example.Data$Variable, ref = c("Horizontal Pattern","Vertical Pattern","Mesh Pattern","Diagonal Pattern"))

example_plot<-ggplot(Example.Data, aes(x=Variable, y=Value, fill=Fill)) + theme_bw() + #facet_wrap(~Product, nrow=1)+ #Ensure theme_bw are there to create borders
  theme(legend.position = "none")+
  scale_fill_grey(start=.4)+
  #scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 100), breaks = (seq(0,100,by = 10)))+
  geom_bar(position=position_dodge(.9), stat="identity", colour="black", legend = FALSE, width=0.333333333)
```

How can I return the input value for `width` (0.3333333) in `geom_bar` above?

I can print the `position` as follows:

```
contents_struct_of_layers = capture.output(str(example_plot$layers))
#splits width lines into list
split_string<-as.list(strsplit(contents_struct_of_layers[39], " ")[[1]])
input_position_dodge<-as.numeric(split_string[10])
input_position_dodge
```

However after reviewing the contents of `example.plot` I can't locate the corresponding value for `geom_bar` `position`.

You can view the structure of `example.plot` and it's various components with the following code:

```
str(example_plot$layers)
```

or

str(example_plot$theme)

etc.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the width in `example_plot$layers[[1]]$geom_params$width`

Comment: That's fabulous. Thank you very much.